# Docker : unable to pull mongodb image

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm new to docker and mongodb and when I try to pull the mongo image either from the powershell or the command prompt in windows 10 it starts loading and after a day it is still at a point where many feature downloads are complete but not all

This appears in my command prompt :

```
 3889bb8d808b: Downloading [>                                                  ]  555.3kB/4.07GB                         
 d0099407ec8c: Downloading [>                                                  ]  1.669MB/1.658GB                        
 5171ed01a068: Download complete                                                                                         
 1a316c4dbc30: Download complete                                                                                          
 7e05862ade99: Download complete                                                                                         
 f7bdc8ea0d50: Download complete
```

All the codes below the first two have the download completed the first two codes have increased just a little in the period of one day . All other images I have pulled have been downloaded fast and completely. 
  I have tried pulling the mongo image in different ways but the result is the same :

```
    docker pull mongo
    docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mongodb mongo:4.0.4 //deploy image for first time
```

I have also tried switching to linux containers but I get that I don't have enough memory and I can't .I don't know if switching to linux containers can fix this issue .

I would appreciate your guidance with helping me pull the mongo image .

Comment: Could you please remove the Powershell tag as this is not related to Powershell code? Thanks in advance.